# Gtk Modelcolumn and vector with union

Tags: c++, vector, boost, gtkmm

I was able to create columns from a text file, but these are only strings.

I use this to resize the vector, but there are only Glib::ustrings. So i heard of union or something like boost:variant but i cant figure out how to give for example test[0] the datatype Glib:ustring and test[1] the type bool and so on. Or is there another much easier way to handle columns in GTKmm

```
union DTypes
{
    Glib::ustring s;
    bool b;
    int i;
};

class ModelColumns : public Gtk::TreeModel::ColumnRecord
{
public:


    std::vector<Gtk::TreeModelColumn<Glib::ustring>> test;


    void append_column()
    {
        ++t_size;
        test.resize(t_size);
        add (test[t_size-1]);
    }
private:
    int t_size=0;
};
```

Btw it IS working, every column exists.

```
    m_refTreeModel = Gtk::ListStore::create(m_Columns);
    m_TreeView.set_model(m_refTreeModel);
    m_refTreeSelection = m_TreeView.get_selection();
    m_refTreeSelection->signal_changed().connect( sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MyWindow::on_selection_changed));

    for (int i=0; i<categorycount; i++)
    {
        m_TreeView.append_column_editable(category[i].substr(ci_count),m_Columns.test[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Unions can only be used with Plain Old Data types such as `int`, `char`, `float`. Most classes can not be used in a union and `Glib::ustring` certainly can not be used.